# How do I apply my function to non-nil elements only?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this concise function that trims (strips) strings in my array

```
data_cols = data_cols.collect{|x| x.strip || x }
```

However if one of the elements in the array is nil, the above falls apart.  How can I modify the above so that it won’t apply to nil elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove `nil` values from the array entirely, you can use [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-compact):

```
cols.compact.map { |col| col.strip } 
# or 
cols.compact.map(&:strip)
```

If you want to keep all values, but only operate on the non-nil values, you can simply use a nil-guard:

```
# straightforward, no magic, works across rubies:
cols.map { |col| col && col.strip }

# a wee dose of magic in ruby 2.3 (safe navigation operator)
cols.map { |col| col&.strip }
```

Finally, if you want to be more idiomatic and ruby-esque, you can use duck-typing and let the objects sort out themselves whether or not they can be "strip'ped":

```
cols.map { |col| col.respond_to?(:strip) ? col.strip : col }
```

Comment: I'm glad you referred to the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). A few points: 1) `col && col.strip || col` can be simplified to `col && col.strip`, 2) `[false] .map { |col| col.strip if col.respond_to?(:strip) } #=> [nil]`, 3) As there is no mention in the question of removing `nil`s, I suggest you move the first part of your answer to the end and strike "keep all values, but ".

Comment: @CarySwoveland 1) Good catch; updated. 2) Fixed. 3) I think it's useful in the broader context of this type of question, and it provides an opportunity to illustrate the common `<symbol>.to_proc` idiom within this context. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try`

```
data_cols = data_cols.collect{|x| x.try(:strip) }
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you still want the nil values in your result array. If not, you can just use [compact](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-compact):

```
data_cols = data_cols.compact.collect{|x| x.strip || x }
```

compact will remove all the nil values in the array.

If you want to keep nil values, you need to change your condition:

```
data_cols = data_cols.compact.collect{|x| x ? x.strip : nil }
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: if `x` is falsey but non-nil in your second example, it's replaced with `nil`. Might be desirable, but might also introduce an unexpected condition.